# How to get access token from ACAccount object Social.framework

Tags: facebook, security, twitter, ios6, social-framework

I have an iOS application and users log in through facebook or twitter. I'm using social.framework to authenticate users and I need to send their access tokens to the server to verify their credentials.

How can I get the access token if [NCAccount credential] always returns null regarding to apple documentation?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019

Answer (score -1):

I used this library for twitter 
https://github.com/kbegeman/Twitter-Reverse-Auth

And the facebook.framework for Facebook with the following function

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {}];
```